# "Press" a key from inside an interactive function

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I need to programmatically press a key from inside of an interactive function.  Here's an outline of what I have so far:

```
(defun answer-to-life-the-universe-and-everything ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "(* 6 7)")
  ;; Need to automagically press the RETURN key here
)
```

My use case: in a REPL buffer, I need frequently execute a long command.  I can use the above code to create an interactive function that inserts the required string, but I still have to hit RETURN manually for the REPL to read it.  Terminating the string with \n or \r won't do what I need it to.

How can I do this inside of my interactive function definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler way to do this is to find out what command the `enter` key is bound to in the REPL and then call that command in your interactive function.  (To find out, go to the REPL buffer and hit `C-h k <return>`.)

For example, `enter` is bound to `inferior-ess-send-input` when using the `R` REPL via `ess`, so this command inserts the string and "hits enter":

```
(defun try-this ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "print(\"hi\")")
  (inferior-ess-send-input))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed (cider-repl-return in my case)!

Comment: @YosemiteMark Take a look at [Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros).  They are made for this kind of commands.  In your specific case, type `C-x (`, do whatever you want to do, then type `C-x )`, and `C-x C-k C-e`.  This pops up a buffer with lists all commands that where executed by whatever you did between starting and ending the macro.